# Grant create any database permission

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've provisioned an azure sql db. The server admin login used to provision the resource (and also visible in the portal) is a user in master and a server login. I've given it the dbmanager and loginmanager roles, but when I try to run 'GRANT CREATE DATABASE to [user]', I'm getting an error that grantor does not have permissions. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you followed this document: [Database creators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#database-creators)?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I login my Azure SQL database with `ServerAdmin`, tried the same operation and get the same error when running the `GRANT CREATE DATABASE to [user]` statements.

[image]

But according the document [Additional server-level administrative roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#additional-server-level-administrative-roles), you're creating the server-level administrative roles.

```
CREATE LOGIN Mary WITH PASSWORD = '<strong_password>';
CREATE USER Mary FROM LOGIN Mary;
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER Mary;
ALTER ROLE loginmanager  ADD MEMBER Mary;
```

After these step:

> Now the user can connect to the `master` database and can create new databases.

You don't need to execute `GRANT CREATE DATABASE to [user]` since user has already be a `dbmanager` and `loginmanger` member.

You can connect to you database with the new user and create new database now.

Hope this helps.